# Unity equivalent for Ninject's Bind.ToMethod Using CQRS

Tags: c#, ninject, unity-container, ioc-container, cqrs

I am following this CQS tuturiol https://github.com/Code-First/CQS-Sample and it uses Ninject.

I currently am using Unity and trying to convert this:

```
    Bind<IQueryFactory>().ToMethod(t => new QueryFactory(x => Container.Current.Resolve(x))).InTransientScope();
```

MY query factory is shown below:

```
public class QueryFactory : IQueryFactory
{
    private readonly Func<Type, object> _resolveCallback;

    public QueryFactory(Func<Type, object> resolveCallback)
    {
        _resolveCallback = resolveCallback;
    }

    public T ResolveQuery<T>()
        where T : class, IQuery
    {
        return _resolveCallback(typeof (T)) as T;
    }
}
```

I have tried `container.RegisterType<IQueryFactory>(t => new InjectionFactory(u => u.Resolve(u)));` but that doesnt work.

Comment: The query model given by that article is limiting, because the `IQuery` interface isn't generic. I would advice a model as explained [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd think that an InjectionFactory would be the way to go.  This compiles:

```
container.RegisterType<IQueryFactory>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionFactory((c, x, o) => new QueryFactory(t => c.Resolve(x))));
```

The problem is that the type x is always IQueryFactory so that doesn't get the results you want which is to return an IQuery.

Unfortunately, I don't think the current design fits with Unity very well.

However, with some slight modifications you can get the factory working.  There are a few different ways of doing this (e.g. you could inject the container in the factory and resolve from there) however in this example I'll use a dictionary.

First we change the factory definition:

```
public class QueryFactory : IQueryFactory
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, Func<IQuery>> _factoryQueries;

    public QueryFactory(IDictionary<Type, Func<IQuery>> factoryQueries)
    {
        this._factoryQueries = factoryQueries;
    }

    public T ResolveQuery<T>() where T : class, IQuery
    {
        return this._factoryQueries[typeof(T)]() as T;
    }
```

Basically, the `Func<Type, object> resolveCallback` is swapped for an IDictionary containing Funcs for creating all supported IQuery types.

Next register the IDictionary and the IQueryFactory:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

// Register all IQuery's
container.RegisterType<IActiveUsersQuery, ActiveUsersQuery>();
container.RegisterType<IUserByEmailQuery, UserByEmailQuery>();

IDictionary<Type, Func<IQuery>> factoryQueries = new Dictionary<Type, Func<IQuery>>()
{
    { typeof(IActiveUsersQuery), () => container.Resolve<IActiveUsersQuery>() },
    { typeof(IUserByEmailQuery), () => container.Resolve<IUserByEmailQuery>() },
};

// Register mapping
container.RegisterInstance<IDictionary<Type, Func<IQuery>>>(factoryQueries);
container.RegisterType<IQueryFactory, QueryFactory>();

var factory = container.Resolve<IQueryFactory>();

factory.ResolveQuery<IActiveUsersQuery>().Execute();
factory.ResolveQuery<IActiveUsersQuery>().Execute();
```

As mentioned, a simpler QueryFactory approach that takes a dependency on the container is:

```
public class QueryFactory : IQueryFactory
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    public QueryFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public T ResolveQuery<T>()
        where T : class, IQuery
    {
        return this.container.Resolve(typeof(T)) as T;
    }
}
```

However, some would object to having the factory depend on the container implementation.

Another approach would be to get rid of the factory approach and inject the queries directly; this would make the dependencies obvious but I can see the scenario where you would want to dynamically get a query based on the command type.  Also, I've seen relations between commands and queries which could be handled with open generics resolved in the composition root.